# Debian packages on Xubuntu, install debchange / dch?

Tags: package, deb, debian-based

For creating debian packages on Xubuntu Where from to install debchange / dch?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You want the devscripts package.

You can use the search forms at http://packages.debian.org/ or the similar ones at http://packages.ubuntu.com/ to find out this sort of thing. Click [here](http://packages.debian.org/search?mode=exactfilename&suite=wheezy&section=all&arch=any&searchon=contents&keywords=debchange) to see some sample results.

Answer (score 15):

```
apt-get install devscripts
```

It contains lots of useful scripts for Debian Development (including: dch, debuild, uscan, uupdate and many others).